# In American English, why is the past tense of "plan" spelt "planned"?

Tags: past-tense, american-english, spelling

In American English, a lot of words are spelt with a single consonant plus "-ed", rather than two consonants as you often find in British English. Why isn't "plan" spelt with a single consonant?

Comment: *Planned* is never spelled *planed*, in any dialect. Could you provide a better example? *Traveled/travelled*, for instance ...

Comment: @StoneyB well spotted, fixed! I meant to ask "Why doesn't the Americanism occur with "Planned""?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As chrylis observes, there is no distinction in AE/BE spelling of the inflections of words ending in a stressed syllable like *plan*. The duplication consistently indicates the pronunciation.

The ‘American’ practice (which is no longer exclusively US) of declining to double these final consonants applies only to final consonants of **unstressed** syllables. ***Tra**vel* is inflected as *traveling* and *traveled* rather than *travelling* and *travelled*, but *re**fer*** is inflected with duplication, *referred* and *referring*.

To an unsophisticated American eye, a spelling with unexpected duplication like *travelling* suggests that its user pronounces the syllable *-vel-* with with a 'short e' [ɛ] and stressed (like the composer Ravel) rather than with a schwa [ə] and unstressed.

I suspect that to an unsophisticated British eye, a spelling with unexpected non-duplication like *traveling* suggests that its user pronounces the syllable with a 'long e' [i:] and stressed (like *reveal*).

Answer (score 3):

When forming past tenses with "-ed" or progressives with "-ing", final consonants are generally doubled in cases where the obscure rules of English pronunciation would change the vowel sound without them. "Plan" has a short "a" sound, and using two "n"s in "planned" and "planning" keeps it short. Otherwise, the past tense would be "planed" with a long "a", which is the past tense of "plane".