# Cancel(l)ed vs cancellation

Tags: american-english, spelling, style

> **cancel**, vb., makes *canceled* and *canceling* in AmE. Yet, in cancellation the *-l-* is doubled (-*ll*-) because the accent falls on
> the third syllable.

[It's etymology is](https://oed.com/oed2/00032278)

> **Can·ce(l)·la·tion** Mid-16th c. Latin *cancellat*-, past participle of *cancellare*  (cf. *can·cel·(**l**)ing*)

Longman Pronunciation dictionary reads

> **-ation** *ˈeɪʃən*  bears the primary word
> stress. In words of four or more syllables, a further rhythmic
> (secondary) stress falls two syllables further back (*ˌconsoˈlation,
> conˌsideˈration, neˌgotiˈation, asˌsociˈation*).

*American English spelling  an informal* description reads:

> The nineteenth-century formation *parcellation* can be seen as
> reflecting earlier English spelling, or it can be seen as a very
> conservative instance of *British twinning*, parallel to, say,
> *cancellation*, so rare that there has been no pressure to recognize a
> more regular variant spelling

I don't grasp how to generalize the spelling rule behind [Garner's statement](https://books.google.es/books?id=2xv4CwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA140&dq=%22%20makes%20canceled%20and%20canceling%20in%20AmE%22&hl=es&pg=PA140#v=onepage&q=%22%20makes%20canceled%20and%20canceling%20in%20AmE%22&f=false), so I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

Consonants are usually doubled in stressed syllables, for example, the *t* in 'submit' is in a stressed syllable so it gets doubled in *submi**tt**ing, submi**tt**ed*. By contrast, the *t* in 'elicit' is in an unstressed syllable so it doesn't get doubled in *elici**t**ing, elici**t**ed*. It holds true for both American and British English. (I've written a detailed answer on this topic [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/248082/106592)).

There's an exception to the above rule of thumb:

- *l* in unstressed syllables can either be single or double depending on the variety of English:

  - British English (and some other Englishes such as Canadian and Australian) favours **-ll-** in unstressed syllables as in *travelled travelling*, *cancelled/ cancelling*, *modelled/ modelling* etc.
  - American English usually favours **-l-**, *canceled, traveled, modeled* but the variants with *-ll- are also found (explained [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/248451/106592)).

Garner says ‘in *cancellation* the *-l-* is doubled (*-ll-*) because the accent [=stress] falls on the third [second-last] syllable [can.ce.**LLA**.tion].’ But I don't think that's completely true because compare *interpretation* where the stress falls on the second-last syllable yet the *-t-* doesn't get doubled (**interprettation*).

My understanding is that the *-ll-* in 'cancellation' (and probably other similar words) is etymological. According to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cancellation), 'cancellation' is from Latin *cance**ll**ationem* where the *-ll-* can be seen. And the etymological explanation holds for [*consolation*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/consolation) and [*interpretation*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/interpretation) too.

I've certainly seen *cancelation* but I think that is by analogy with *canceled/ canceling*.

Also read [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/572410/) on ELU (posted after my answer here) which says the same thing about 'cancellation' and adds another important point: “The original double L of Latin *cancello* was simplified to single L in English *cancel*, due to being at the end of the word.”