# When the consonant is doubled in a gerund?

Tags: verbs, gerunds, spelling

Since 'traveling' can be spelled this way , why is the spelling of 'begining' wrong?They are both gerunds which come from a 2 sylable word ending with a consonant.

Comment: What makes you think that they are gerunds?

Comment: well when it has the affix -ing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which one is correct? "cancelled" or "canceled"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83978/which-one-is-correct-cancelled-or-canceled) I know it seems like this isn't exactly the same question, but there is a very good answer there that I think will help you.

Comment: What is a unstressed syllable?

Comment: They are just verbs, simple as that.

Comment: This video on stressed and unstressed syllables may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Sx0r_8-fhQ A very simplistic explanation (I'm no expert on pronunciation):  Syllables in English pronunciation are stressed or unstressed. Stressed syllables are emphasized more than unstressed syllables. In 'apple' the first syllable is stressed and in 'apply' the second syllable is stressed. This means the second syllable in 'apple' is unstressed and the first syllable in 'apply' unstressed.